# PHP: генерация индивидуальных страниц для пользователей с разными идентификаторами

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, пишу свой вк клиент (типа Apidog), и вот возникла проблема:
есть пользователи и у них есть ID, и нужно что б при вводе определенного id открывалась новая вкладка, тоесть так

index.php

*ввели id - 123

index.php/id123

Тоесть генерация странице исходя из страницы, прошу написать скрипт который при переходе на `index.php/***` выводил то что введено в url, спасибо большое, прошу помочь в интернете решений не нашел, помогите, очень нужно!

Comment: GET-параметры не допускается использовать, например, /index.php?id=id123 ? Можно ли отказаться от расширения php, например, /index/id123 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант — это воспользоваться GET-параметрами, т.е. после знака вопроса указать пару ключ-значение, например

```
/index.php?id=id123
```

где `id` — ключ, а `id123` — значение. Тогда в PHP-скрипте вы сможете извлечь это значение при помощи суперглобального массива `$_GET`

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    echo $_GET['id'];
}
```

Более сложный путь, преобразовать URL

```
/index/id123
```

Здесь `index` — неизменная часть, а `id123` — идентификатор. Однако, тут вам потребуется помощь Web-сервера, который должен все такие запросы направлять на единый скрипт, например, index.php. В Apache этого можно добиться при помощи директивы `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^index/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Обратите внимание, мы в конечном итоге получаем точно такой же URL, как и в первом случае, только значение параметра `$1` берется из круглых скобок регулярного выражения.

```
index.php?id=$1
```

Т.е. извлечь значение вы сможете тем же самым PHP-скриптом с использованием суперглобального массива `$_GET`. Если в качестве сервера вы используете nginx, то у него имеется похожая директива `rewrite`:

```
rewrite ^/index/([a-z0-9]+) /index.php?id=$1 last;
```